# Storing and calculating relationships in a one-to-many system

Tags: sql, algorithm, logic, one-to-many

I'm scratching my head, looking for a reasonable way of achieving this. The title was really difficult to figure out, so I'm sorry if you entered this post hoping for something else. It's both a database and a logic question.

I have 100 entries in a "collection". Let's call each one an object. Each object refers to an entry in a database, and has some name (let's say obj1, obj2 ...). Some of these objects are a "compound" of other objects. So, for instance, if obj1 and obj2 are inputs, obj11 is the output (obj1, obj2 -> obj11). Maybe even multiple inputs of the same object: obj1 x 4, obj2, obj11 -> obj21.

I'm looking for a way to calculate the resulting object continuously while changing the input, and thus these relations must have some clever way of being stored in a database, so that a calculation like this can be done in a rather elegant fashion.

Naturally I thought of a many-to-one table, but couldn't find a logical way to then find a result for given inputs without parsing the whole table.

Does anyone have some thoughts on this?

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag would all help.

Comment: Oracle resolution: If you would like to store the collections as collections, you can: 1) define a type which is a collection or varray 2) create a table with the column of the type you defined. You will be able to ingest objects from table by using standard api.

Comment: I was looking for a more general way of doing this. So the sample data is actually in the post, and so is the desired result. Type of database shouldn't matter too much, but I'm using using mssql if it helps. It is more of a logical question: how to save it in a relational database, and how such an algorithm would work, roughly. Edit: Entry for each object in db is its id and its name.

Comment: @Pelle: can you make it more clear what you intend and at least describe, how your "objects" are composed / related. What operations should they support? only summing them up and multiplying them with constants? how deep are the objects nested and are cyclic relationships allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be building a sort of recipe system. Some objects are created from different quantities of other objects. In terms of datastructure, you could have something like

```cpp
   struct Thing {
     std::vector<Ingredient> parts;
     // ... other attributes here
   };

   struct Ingredient {
     Thing component;
     int count;
   };
```

This can be stored using

```
   CREATE TABLE `Things` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
       # ... other attributes here
      PRIMARY KEY `id`
   );

   CREATE TABLE `Ingredients` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,           
      `result_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
      `component_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
      `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
       PRIMARY KEY `id`
   );

   ALTER TABLE `Ingredients` FOREIGN KEY (`result_id`) REFERENCES `Thing` (`id`);
   ALTER TABLE `Ingredients` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `Thing` (`id`);
```

To store the recipe for a `Thing`, just insert all its components and their quantities as ingredients. To retrieve the recipe, just `SELECT` all ingredients with that `result_id`. To see where a `Thing` is used in a recipe, just query for its use as a component.

Imagine that `A` is built from `B` and `C`; and that `B` can be built from `D` and `E`. Then you may want to perform a multi-stage query, to figure out from `A` = `B` + `C` that `A` = (`D` + `E`) + `C`. This requires one extra select on each component, to see if it has, itself, ingredients. However, this will backfire unless your recipes form a tree: what if `A` requires `B` and `B` can be built from `A`?. Even worse: what if there are several means to obtain `A`, say from `B` + `C` or from `X` + `Y`? If you need to distinguish among these alternative recipes, you would need an additional table:

```cpp
   struct Thing {
     std::vector<Recipe> recipes;
     // ... other attributes here
   };

   struct Recipe {
     std::vector<Ingredient> ingredients;
     // ... other attributes here
   };

   struct Ingredient {
     Thing component;
     int count;
   };
```

And, in SQL,

```
   CREATE TABLE `Recipes` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,           
      `result_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
      PRIMARY KEY `id`
   );

   CREATE TABLE `Ingredients` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,           
      `recipe_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
      `component_id` int(11) NOT NULL, 
      `count` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY `id`
   );

   ALTER TABLE `Recipes` FOREIGN KEY (`result_id`) REFERENCES `Thing` (`id`);
   ALTER TABLE `Ingredients` FOREIGN KEY (`recipe_id`) REFERENCES `Recipe` (`id`);
   ALTER TABLE `Ingredients` FOREIGN KEY (`component_id`) REFERENCES `Thing` (`id`);
```

If you need to recover multi-stage recipes on something like this, then you are trying to perform graph queries on a relational database, and may find it a lot easier to use an object-graph database that is intended for just those types of queries.

---

Edit: assuming no cycles, and at most 1 recipe per `Thing`, how do I find what to cook given a list of ingredients? Several approaches are possible.

- If the number of recipes is not truly huge, and the recipes do not change often, just load them all into memory and use set intersection to detect possible recipes. This will be faster than using the DB.
- If you insist in using the DB, this works (and you can [test it online](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/40182a/1):

```
SELECT possible.id 
    FROM (
        SELECT i.result_id AS id, COUNT(*) AS total
        FROM `Ingredients` AS i GROUP BY i.result_id
    ) AS possible, (
        SELECT result_id, COUNT(result_id) AS total
        FROM `Ingredients` AS i WHERE 
            (i.component_id = 1 AND i.count<=1) OR
            (i.component_id = 2 AND i.count<=3) OR
            (i.component_id = 42 AND i.count<=1)
        GROUP BY i.result_id
    ) AS valid
    WHERE possible.id = valid.result_id AND possible.total = valid.total;
```

Comment: Beautiful answer! You understood my question very well. I'll specify that there's only one "recipe" for each object, and thus will always form a tree, which will exclude the complexities mentioned. I see you answered the way to find every recipe that included a particular ingredient, but what if I have three ingredients, and one recipe contains only those three, but another one contains those three plus one more. How do I go about figuring the recipe out then? Wouldn't that be more complex than just searching for it as a component, since it will show up in both?

Comment: I do not understand your question/example. If you want all ingredients needed to make an `A`: `select * from Ingredients where result_id='A'`. The fact that the same ingredients may be useful to make `C` or `D` does not invalidate this, because they will have `result_id='C'` or `result_id='D'` instead.

Comment: I meant in the circumstances where I don't know that the result would be A. So, for instance, if I only know some ingredients, it would seem like a rather expensive operation to figure out which recipe contains those ingredients, and no more. So, it will be a reversed operation of the one given, which in this case would be done in a very different manner, which I'm unsure of.

Comment: See updated answer. Essentially, you build a query `OR`ing together all the ingredients you have on hand, and get back a list of things that you can cook with those ingredients.

Comment: Thank you for the great explanation, and code.  Works perfectly!